# How to change the date format when sending data into the database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

I am using jquery full calendar to show some booking details. I am inserting date into the database  in `("yyyy-MM-dd")` format.

But when i retrieve the title value from the calendar using `var title=$("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').title;` it output as "June 2015". later i am using these two days for a comparison. Therefor i need to either send date into the database in "19 June 2015" format or convert title date value into  "06 2015".

If anyone has a clear idea about this help me. Hope the problem is clear. I am using codeignier and i use the following cotroller method to send the data into the database.

```
function add_reservation() {
        $reservation_model = new Reservation_model();
        $reservation_service = new Reservation_service();

        $reservation_model->set_date_cal(trim($this->input->post('date', TRUE)));
       // $reservation_model->set_date(strtotime($this->input->post('date', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_title(trim($this->input->post('selected_hall', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_type(trim($this->input->post('selected_time', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_description(trim($this->input->post('name', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_advanced_payment_status(trim($this->input->post('optionsRadios', TRUE)));
        //$reservation_model->set_advanced_payment_status(trim($this->input->post('no', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_paid_amount(trim($this->input->post('paid_amount', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_fax(trim($this->input->post('fax', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_telephone_number(trim($this->input->post('telephone', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_address(trim($this->input->post('address', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_menu_no(trim($this->input->post('selected_menu_number', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_menu_price_per_plate(trim($this->input->post('menu_price', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_is_deleted('0');

        $this->db->last_query();

        echo $reservation_service->add_reservation($reservation_model);


}
```

basically i want to change the format of the date which i am sending to the database as "19 June 2015"

Comment: Why you would change the format?

Comment: How are you getting "19 June 2015 ", when you are POSTing only "June 2015" from your HTML page.

Comment: @Jens because i want to compare the date in the database and the date which i am getting from the calendar. For that both should be in the same format. my calendar date comes like "June 2015" and database date comes like "2015-06-19"

Comment: How can you compare `June 2015` with `2015-06-19` ? You consider only Month ?

Comment: @Vishwa I want to get the date as "19 June 2015" from the database. then i can split it and get only "June 2015". Then i can compare calendar date and the date in the database.

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I want to consider Month and the year

Comment: Both of them should be of datatype date. This has no format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change the MySQL format. Change your html OR keep every thing the same way it is now and use javascript to convert it to mysql format.

```
var title=$("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').title; // "June 2015"
var d = new Date(title);
var title = d.getFullYear() + "-" +( d.getMonth() + 1); // "2015-6"
```

Now, you can compare. Let me know, if you are looking for something else.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your the date you have as `2015-06-19` and your DB Date as `June 2015`

```
<?php
$date = "2015-06-19";
$month = date("F", strtotime($date));
$year = date("Y", strtotime($date));
$MyDate = $month.' '.$year;
$MyDBDate = "June 2015";

if ($MyDate == $MyDBDate) 
{
    # Your Action Here
}
```

You can change the condition or dates according to your need.

Here's the [EVAL Link](https://eval.in/384145) for you

**Update :**

Updated with Javascript version to compare as per OP's Request

```
<script>
var MyDate = "<?php echo $MyDate?>";
var MyDBDate = "June 2015";
if (MyDate ==MyDBDate) 
{
    alert('Match');
} else {
    alert('Not a Match');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can we do this comparison in a javascript?

Comment: Yes, It is possible. You want a javascript version ?? :)

Comment: Yeah.It would be better.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out for the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Format date

```
 $newDate = date('d F Y',strtotime($_POST['date']));
```

FROM Database SQL

```
DATE_FORMAT(DateValueDb,'%d %b %Y')
```